# Dynamic SQL select query in Golang

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I am trying to build API, with database/sql and mysql driver, that will read data based on URL parameters.
Something like this

```
myapi.com/users?columns=id,first_name,last_name,country&sort=desc&sortColumn=last_name&limit=10&offset=20
```

I know how to get all columns or just specific columns when it is defined in struct. But I want to know is it possible to get columns from url and instead of predefined struct save it to map and than just scan those columns.
I have working code that will get data from above endpoint only if number of columns is same as in struct. If I remove `country` for example I get error that `Scan` expects 4 params but 3 are given.

I don't need specific code, just some directions since I am learning Go and my background is PHP where this is easier to do.

**Update**

Thanks to answers I have partly working solution.
Here is code:

```
cols := []string{"id", "first_name", "last_name"}
vals := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
w := map[string]interface{}{"id": 105}

var whereVal []interface{}
var whereCol []string

for k, v := range w {
    whereVal = append(whereVal, v)
    whereCol = append(whereCol, fmt.Sprintf("%s = ?", k))
}

for i := range cols {
    vals[i] = new(interface{})
}
err := db.QueryRow("SELECT "+strings.Join(cols, ",")+" FROM users WHERE "+strings.Join(whereCol, " AND "), whereVal...).Scan(vals...)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

b, _ := json.Marshal(vals)
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

This should query `SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE id = 105;`

But how do I get data out to proper json object? Now it prints out strings encoded in base64 like this.

```
[105,"Sm9obm55","QnJhdm8="]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I know (also not much experienced in Go) if you don't assign a real type to value then `Scan` will return `[]byte` and when it is marshalled it returns base64 encoded string.

So you have to assign a type to your columns and if you want proper json then assign keys to values.

In your example it can be done something like this:

```
cols := []string{"id", "first_name", "last_name"}
vals := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
result := make(map[string]interface{}, len(cols))

for i, key := range cols {
    switch key {
    case "id", "status":
        vals[i] = new(int)
    default:
        vals[i] = new(string)
    }

    result[key] = vals[i]
}

b, _ := json.Marshal(result)
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

So, instead of looping over `cols` and creating new interface for each column, now we are creating key/value pairs and assigning type based on column name.

Also, if you have nullable columns in table, and you probably have, then you'll get error because `nil` can't go into `string`. So I suggest this package `gopkg.in/guregu/null.v3` and then assign type like `null.String`. That way you'll get back `null` as a value.

For example:

```
for i, key := range cols {
    switch key {
    case "id", "status":
        vals[i] = new(int)
    case "updated_at", "created_at":
        vals[i] = new(null.Time)
    default:
        vals[i] = new(null.String)
    }

    result[key] = vals[i]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option that a found to return dynamic resultset, you will need a interface{} array but you have to assign to a new(interface{}) to get a pointer that can be write by Scan method

```
//...
types, _ := rows.ColumnTypes()  
for rows.Next() {
 row := make([]interface{}, len(types))
 for i := range types {
    row[i] = new(interface{})
 }
 rows.Scan(row...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must first fetch the result columns count and then don't exceed the size.

If you meant the query fields, you need dynamic create the query string, the params size must be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a query statement with the dynamic fields(use placeholder for avoiding sql injection):

```
rows := db.QueryRow("SELECT {{YOUR_FIELDS}} from table_tbl")
```

Create variable carrier with the same size of columns

```
vals := make([]interface{}, len(rows.Columns()))
```

Use sql.RawBytes for field's type if you don't need type checking or can't know their types, otherwise use the same type of field.

```
for i, _ := range cols {
    vals[i] = new(sql.RawBytes)
    //check column name, if it is id, and you know it is integer
    //vals[i] = new(int)
}
```

Iterate rows and scan

```
for rows.Next() {
    err = rows.Scan(vals...)
}
```